# How to set the Synapse pipeline parameter during deployment?

Tags: azure-synapse

How to set the Synapse integrate pipeline parameter during deployment?

I am using the Synapse deployment task with GIT to deploy the workspace to multiple environments. There is one parameter that is environment specific that I need to pass to the job.
[image]

I don't see this parameter in the TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json in the workspace_publish branch.
Is it supposed to show up here or do I need to follow some other method to set the parameter to Synapse Integrate Pipelines?

Comment: Hi Xavier, did you ever resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are expecting a **variable** in the ARM template .json file as shared in the screenshot. Pass the same value as parameter and check after publishing if that appears in the ARM template inside workspace_publish branch or not.

Comment: I have tried variable and parameter, neither appears in the ARM template.